# Draw shape with 4 points and pull angles via user Event Touch(on this points)

Tags: android, xamarin, touch, shapes, user-interaction

I want to make an shape with **4 points**,then draw and provide to pull angles for user,via touch Events.
E.g. i have an ImageView,where ill fill with an image taken from gallery/camera(nevermind), after that must appear that Shape **with 4 points**(i think that each point will be an image as little circle) and user can change angles via touch to this Point.
This points is like coordinate,where i want to get this values and make some kind of Perpesctive. 
[image: Exmaple,what i need]

In others words:

1. ImageView filled with image -> Appears drawed shape with 4 points
2. User put this points as he want
3. When work is done,take this coordinates to make an perspective.

So how can i achieve this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, this article [helped](http://knowandroidmore.blogspot.md/2013/05/resizable-rectangle-overlay-on-touch.html) me a lot. Pretty the same(trivial).

```
 public class DrawView extends View {

    Point point1, point3;
    Point point2, point4;

    /**
     * point1 and point 3 are of same group and same as point 2 and point4
     */
    int groupId = -1;
    private ArrayList<ColorBall> colorballs = new ArrayList<ColorBall>();
    // array that holds the balls
    private int balID = 0;
    // variable to know what ball is being dragged
    Paint paint;
    Canvas canvas;

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
        // setting the start point for the balls
        point1 = new Point();
        point1.x = 50;
        point1.y = 20;

        point2 = new Point();
        point2.x = 150;
        point2.y = 20;

        point3 = new Point();
        point3.x = 150;
        point3.y = 120;

        point4 = new Point();
        point4.x = 50;
        point4.y = 120;

        // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point1));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point2));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point3));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point4));

    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
        // setting the start point for the balls
        point1 = new Point();
        point1.x = 50;
        point1.y = 20;

        point2 = new Point();
        point2.x = 150;
        point2.y = 20;

        point3 = new Point();
        point3.x = 150;
        point3.y = 120;

        point4 = new Point();
        point4.x = 50;
        point4.y = 120;

        // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point1));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point2));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point3));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point4));

    }

    // the method that draws the balls
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC); //if you want another background color

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        // mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55FFFFFF"));

        if (groupId == 1) {
            canvas.drawRect(point1.x + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                    point3.y + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point3.x
                            + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point1.y
                            + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(point2.x + colorballs.get(1).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                    point4.y + colorballs.get(3).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point4.x
                            + colorballs.get(3).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point2.y
                            + colorballs.get(1).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
        }
        BitmapDrawable mBitmap;
        mBitmap = new BitmapDrawable();

        // draw the balls on the canvas
        for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                    new Paint());
        }
    }

    // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();

        int X = (int) event.getX();
        int Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (eventaction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on
                                        // a ball
            balID = -1;
            groupId = -1;
            for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
                // get the center for the ball
                Utils.logd("Id : " + ball.getID());
                Utils.logd("getX : " + ball.getX() + " getY() : " + ball.getY());
                int centerX = ball.getX() + ball.getWidthOfBall();
                int centerY = ball.getY() + ball.getHeightOfBall();
                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the ball
                double radCircle = Math
                        .sqrt((double) (((centerX - X) * (centerX - X)) + (centerY - Y)
                                * (centerY - Y)));

                Utils.logd("X : " + X + " Y : " + Y + " centerX : " + centerX
                        + " CenterY : " + centerY + " radCircle : " + radCircle);

                if (radCircle < ball.getWidthOfBall()) {

                    balID = ball.getID();
                    Utils.logd("Selected ball : " + balID);
                    if (balID == 1 || balID == 3) {
                        groupId = 2;
                        canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y,
                                paint);
                    } else {
                        groupId = 1;
                        canvas.drawRect(point2.x, point4.y, point4.x, point2.y,
                                paint);
                    }
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                }
                invalidate();
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag with the ball
            // move the balls the same as the finger
            if (balID > -1) {
                Utils.logd("Moving Ball : " + balID);

                colorballs.get(balID).setX(X);
                colorballs.get(balID).setY(Y);

                paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

                if (groupId == 1) {
                    colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(0).getX());
                    colorballs.get(1).setY(colorballs.get(2).getY());
                    colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
                    colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(0).getY());
                    canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y,
                            paint);
                } else {
                    colorballs.get(0).setX(colorballs.get(1).getX());
                    colorballs.get(0).setY(colorballs.get(3).getY());
                    colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(3).getX());
                    colorballs.get(2).setY(colorballs.get(1).getY());
                    canvas.drawRect(point2.x, point4.y, point4.x, point2.y,
                            paint);
                }

                invalidate();
            }

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

            break;
        }
        // redraw the canvas
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    public void shade_region_between_points() {
        canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried the code snippet you posted, but it seems to just resize the rectangle when pulling the corners. How did you change the code to change angles instead?